# How to save an embedded object in GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to save a datastore entity reference within another:

```
class Save(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):

        order = Order(parent=ndb.Key('Orders', 'default_orders'))

        order.special_request     = self.request.get('specialRequirement')
        order.product_type        = self.request.get('productType')

        customer = Customer(parent=ndb.Key('Customer', 'default_customers'))

        customer.name              = self.request.get('customerName')
        customer.email             = self.request.get('email')
        customer.put()

        order.customer             = customer
        order.put()
```

The Customer class is simply:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class Customer(ndb.Model):
    name    = ndb.StringProperty()
    email   = ndb.StringProperty()
```

Whilst I've done similar with Rails and mongodb before, I'm not sure what this is called in GAE and am having a hard time searching for examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the following seems to have been my oversight, simply passing the key as:

```
oder.customer           = customer.key
```

I now have a usable reference to the embedded object and both are being saved correctly.

Comment: This isn't an "embedded object" it is a reference to the customer. `order.customer` just holds the key of the `customer`.  You will have to fetch the object.  If you delete order customer will be untouched.